# lapply on each element of a list of lists

Tags: r, image, list, lapply

How can I perform the same function (here: load.image) on each element of a list of lists?

Starting point is this list of two lists:

```
list1 <- list(c("Group1", "Group2", "Group3"))
list2 <- list(c("GroupA", "GroupB", "GroupC"))
list.all <- c(list1,list2)
```

I wrote this function that applies lapply iteratively:

```
    images.list.function <- lapply(
      designs.path.list, 
      FUN = function(secondlevel.list) 
        lapply(secondlevel.list, function(x) load.image(x))
    )
    # read all jpgs into a list
    images.list <- images.list.function
    images.list
```

This works correctly, but I want a format that is independent from the number of levels because in the future, a third or fourth level might be added.

Any elegant thoughts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a new solution that is even simpler than R. Schifini's elegant solution, so now I answer my own question :)

The apply family also provides a recursive version called `rapply`, and it works perfectly on nested lists, see [these examples](https://www.r-bloggers.com/rapply-function-explanation-and-examples/).

Applying that to the problem, the solution is simply:

```
images.list <- rapply(designs.path.list, load.image)
```

That's really all.

Answer (score 1):

Is this useful?

```
flatList = unlist(list.all)
[1] "Group1" "Group2" "Group3" "GroupA" "GroupB" "GroupC"
```

Using `unlist` you'll end up with a vector. Then use `lapply` with your image loading function.

For example, using the `paste` function to add `"-image"` to every name:

```
d = lapply(flatList, function(x){paste(x, "-image", sep = "")})
> d
[[1]]
[1] "Group1-image"

[[2]]
[1] "Group2-image"

[[3]]
[1] "Group3-image"

[[4]]
[1] "GroupA-image"

[[5]]
[1] "GroupB-image"

[[6]]
[1] "GroupC-image"
```

Comment: @R.Schifni this is a really elegant trick! thanks and sorry for the delay, missed the notification. but I can still use it in my current code.

Answer (score 0):

I like R. Schifini's answer. But just to spice it up a bit, you also have access to do.call.

Just do a do call repetitively as many levels as you need:

```
do.call(c,do.call(c,list.all))...
```

that should give you a vector of all items...

Comment: Showing how this applies to OP's problem (using their sample data and giving the output) would make this a much better answer.

Comment: @Jorge Lopez thanks for your idea but i wanted something that is independent from knowing how many levels there are

Comment: I think Agile Bean perfectly understood what I meant, Nick. My answer is supposed to be directed to the person to whom I'm writing to, irrespective of what 3rd persons might find as a valid response or not. But, thanks for writing a line, Nick. See how my answers are meant to be understood mainly only to the person I'm writing to?